# Полиморфные связи и БД в Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, relation

Представим 3 таблицы

```
articles (id, slug)
news(id, slug)
langs(id, lang_id, entity_id, entity_type)
```

Связь у них morphMany с langs. Как можно добавить каскадное удаление для articles и для news одновременно ? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Через [event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) может быть?

Comment: Спасибо, помог!